# WPF find clicked button closest parent (TabItem) and close it

Tags: c#, wpf

I am wondering whether there is a better simpler way rewrite the following code find the closest parent which is a TabItem and remove it from the TabControl.

I have a TabControl where I add new TabItems dynamically. I assign a `HeaderTemplate` to each tab which looks like this;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AttorneyTabHeader">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="THE title" Margin="2,0,0,0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Width="Auto" UseLayoutRounding="False" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" Click="CloseAttorneysTabButtonClick">
            <Image Source="/images/close-cross-thin-circular-button/close-cross-thin-circular-button16.png" Height="16"></Image>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The header has a close button and I would like to close the TabItem whenever the button is clicked. My click handler looks like this;

```
public void CloseAttorneysTabButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TabItem this_tab = (TabItem)((Button)sender).Parent.GetParentObject().GetParentObject().GetParentObject().GetParentObject().GetParentObject().GetParentObject();
    AttorneysTabControl.Items.Remove(this_tab);
}
```

I am wondering whether there is a better way to rewrite this because now I am depending on getting the parent over and over again suppose I change the button and forget changing the handler.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a few ways you can handle it, but the simplest is likely to bind to the `TabItem` in the `Tag` property for the `Button` so that you can use it in your event handler.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TabHeaderTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="The Title" Margin="2 0 0 0" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Width="Auto" UseLayoutRounding="False"
                BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent"
                Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Mode=OneWay}"
                Click="Button_Click">
            <Image Source="images/close.png" Height="16" />
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now your event handler can be relatively simple, and doesn't need to know as much as it does in your example.

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button button && button.Tag is TabItem item) {
        var tabControl = (TabControl)item.Parent;
        tabControl.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```